# How to get list of visible QModelIndex in QAbstractItemView

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qmodelindex, qabstractitemview

Is there any way to get a list of currently visible items in `QAbstractItemView`? And, if it possible, to receive any notifications about changing of this list.

Upd:
I'm asking exactly about `QAbstractItemView` or `QTreeView` with non-plain structure, not `QTableView`.

Upd2:
I'm implementing tree view model with checkboxes. I want next behavior (same for checking/uncheking):

- If one of checkbox is checked - then all childs must be checked
- If all child checkboxes are checked - then parent check box should be checked too. And same for parent of parent, and so on...

Check state are monitored/modified by external data source, so I need a mechanism to update all changed children/parents. `dataChanged` signal is not enough for me because it is very expansive to build a list of all changed `QModelIndex` for updating. And it is not necessary at all, because all fresh data will be picked from `QAbstractItemModel::data`.

I found next dirty hack to update all items: `emit dataChanged( QModelIndex(), QModelIndex() );` but it's undocumented for invalid indexes.

So, I need a way to force all visible items redraw they content with fresh data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are no cases where list of visible items is required. In case of correct model implementation, all items are updated automatically.

Hard part of implementation — force children and parents to update. I wrote the following code:

```cpp
bool TreeModel::setData( const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role )
    case Qt::CheckStateRole:
    {
        TreeItemList updateRangeList;  // Filled with items, in which all childred must be updated
        TreeItemList updateSingleList; // Filled with items, which must be updated
        item->setCheckState( value.toBool(), updateRangeList, updateSingleList ); // All magic there
        
        foreach ( TreeAbstractItem *i, updateRangeList )
        {
            const int nRows = i->rowCount();
            QModelIndex topLeft = indexForItem( i->m_childs[0] );
            QModelIndex bottomRight = indexForItem( i->m_childs[nRows - 1] );
            emit dataChanged( topLeft, bottomRight );
        }
        foreach ( TreeAbstractItem *i, updateSingleList )
        {
            QModelIndex updateIndex = indexForItem( i );
            emit dataChanged( updateIndex, updateIndex );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

You can get the topleft and bottom right cell by calling:

```
tableview->indexAt(tableview->rect().topLeft())
tableview->indexAt(tableview->rect().bottomRight())
```

To get notification of change, reimplement the virtual function of qabstractscrollarea

```
scrollContentsBy
```

This function is called when the view port is scrolled.
call QTableView::scrollContentsBy and then do whatever you need to.

Comment: I'm not asking about simple QTableView, it's clear for me...
I'm asking about custom tree-based view with my own items delegate. Scroll notofication are not enough because they will not cover expand and collapse events.

Comment: You can still use the indexAt to get the indices in the viewport. And connect scroll expand and collapse signals to a slot that will recalculate the indices. I think if you don't wanna do something dirty, like intercept the paint method, then connecting to all existing signals that change the viewport is the way to go.

Comment: indexAt is not acceptable, because I use QTreeView and some of items doesn't fit all row. See update of original question.

Comment: `rect().topLeft()` is by [definition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#rect-prop) always `(0,0)`. For QTreeView, the visualRect for an index does for some reason exclude the expand/collaps triangle icon, so `visualRect().left() >= 20` in my case. Therefore indexAt should not work. For some reason it still works... but I would be sceptical maybe this is unintended behavior (or an undocumented special case).

Answer (score 4):

For `QTreeView`, the list of visible items can be traversed like this:

```
QTreeView& tv (yourTreeView);

// Get model index for first visible item
QModelIndex modelIndex = tv.indexAt(tv.rect().topLeft());

while (modelIndex.isValid())
{
    // do something with the item indexed by modelIndex
    ...
    // This navigates to the next visible item
    modelIndex = tv.indexBelow(modelIndex);
}
```

Comment: There may be no index at top-left. It depends on style paddings / delegates implementation and other stuff.

Comment: // This navigates to the next visible item
    modelIndex = tv.indexBelow(modelIndex);   Will loop till end of the tree. May be here only we can put one more check if its in tv.rect() regeion , we can break the loop or check ItemAt(index). & check if y- axis value is grated than tv.tect.bottomLeft().y() thank break the loop.

Comment: To be more exact indexBelow, seems to traverse all expanded items not just those visible in the viewport. Also, instead of comparing with tv.rect(), I think tv.viewport.rect() should be used because it accounts for the tree/table header. As for the indexAt( topLeft() ) issue mentioned by @DmitrySazonov I opened an issue / question [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77772).

Answer (score 1):

**Method  1**

```
i, j = table.indexAt(table.rect().topLeft()).row(), table.indexAt(table.rect().bottomLeft()).row() - 1
```

**Method 2**

```
i, j = table.rowAt(0), table.rowAt(table.height()) - 1
```

Comment: It doesn't work for tree view.

Answer (score 0):

i always update whole QAbstractTableModel with:

```
emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(rowCount(), columnCount()-1)); // update whole view
```

Comment: `emit dataChanged( QModelIndex{}, QModelIndex{} );` looks better and more efficient.