# Select QStandardItem inside a QTreeView based on another QTreeView's QStandardItem's visual position

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

i have a lot of data that i represent as QStandardItems inside two QTreeViews. I want to retrieve the visual position of an item inside the *left* tree in order to align the selection of it with the item inside the *right* tree. The user should be able to double-click on the desired item inside the left tree, afterwards which the right tree should represent the item corresponding to his selection. So far im using a function with the *doubleClicked* signal of the left tree as starting point for the logic.

```
self.tree_view_left.doubleClicked.connect(self.double_clicked)
```

Inside of *double_clicked* im retrieving the current index of the left tree and then im searching for his equivalent inside the right tree (*NOTE* i want to match only roots - not child elements).

```
    def double_clicked(self):
        index = self.selection_model.currentIndex()
        tree_left = self.tree_view_left
        tree_right = self.tree_view_right
        if index.isValid():
            item = index.model().itemFromIndex(index)
            if item.hasChildren():
                item_search = tree_right .model().findItems(item.text(), 
                Qt.MatchRecursive)
            # TODO: Find/Calc visual position of StandardItem inside TreeView
            left_vis_item = tree_left.indexAt(tree_left.rect().topLeft())
            right_vis_item =  tree_left.indexAt(tree_left.rect().bottomRight())
            # TODO: Move vertical scrollbar of right TreeView based on that visual position
            # Change right slider position
            tree_right.scrollTo(item_search[0].index())
            tree_right.selectionModel().select(item_search[0].index(), QItemSelectionModel.Select)
```

I have found similiar issues in the forum [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/59132/solved-scroll-to-item-in-treeview), [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54647-Scroll-to-column-in-QTreeWidget) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817429/how-to-get-list-of-visible-qmodelindex-in-qabstractitemview), but either they had a used a different widget (QTreeWidget) or they used a function which i cannot implement (QAbstractItemView::visualRect. My approach was at first to retrieve the visual position by finding out the visible indices (*left_vis_item, right_vis_item*), but then i thought of using the *mouse position*. The last one is new to me. Any ideas?

*EDIT*: I have now added a MRE with a bare minimum of data from a mockup created with this [website](https://extendsclass.com/csv-generator.html). The **MainWindow** Class, which holds (here minimum) main features, looks like this:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("Example")
    window_geometry = self.frameGeometry()
    center_screen = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    window_geometry.moveCenter(center_screen)
    self.move(window_geometry.topLeft())
    group_box_left = QGroupBox('1. Tree view')
    group_box_right = QGroupBox('2. Tree view')
    self.tree_view_left = QTreeView(self)
    self.tree_view_left.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    tree_view_left_header = self.tree_view_left.header()
    tree_view_left_header.setDefaultSectionSize(200)
    tree_model_left = QStandardItemModel()
    self.tree_view_right = QTreeView(self)
    tree_model_right = QStandardItemModel()
    # Add data
    with open("mockup.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    self.import_data(data, tree_model_left)
    self.import_data(data, tree_model_right)
    # Use filled model for tree view
    self.tree_view_left.setModel(tree_model_left)
    self.tree_view_left.setVisible(True)
    self.tree_view_left.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(False)
    self.tree_view_right.setModel(tree_model_right)
    self.selection_model = self.tree_view_left.selectionModel()
    self.tree_view_left.doubleClicked.connect(self.double_clicked)
    # Layout
    hor_box_left = QVBoxLayout()
    hor_box_left.addWidget(self.tree_view_left)
    group_box_left.setLayout(hor_box_left)
    hor_box_right = QVBoxLayout()
    hor_box_right.addWidget(self.tree_view_right)
    group_box_right.setLayout(hor_box_right)
    main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    main_layout.addWidget(group_box_left)
    main_layout.addWidget(group_box_right)
    main_layout.setContentsMargins(100, 0, 100, 0)
    main_layout.setSpacing(50)
    widget = QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(main_layout)
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

And the function for data import is:

```
def import_data(self, data, model):
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        root = QStandardItem(str(i))
        root.appendRows([QStandardItem(data[i]["Firstname"]), QStandardItem(data[i]["Lastname"]),
                         QStandardItem(data[i]["City"])])
        model.appendRow(root)
```

I will explain the issue with snapshots. In the first snapshot you can see that there is an offset between the selected item in the left Tree and the right.[image: Offset explained]. The desired behaviour would be to remove this offset. The current implementation works with no offset **ONLY if the items are collapsed** (which will not always be the case) [image: Without offset]. I will also provide the used data for this example below:

```
[
{
    "Firstname": "Dotty",
    "Lastname": "O'Neill",
    "City": "Tucson"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Libbie",
    "Lastname": "Shuler",
    "City": "Surat Thani"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Caressa",
    "Lastname": "Henebry",
    "City": "Tucson"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Larine",
    "Lastname": "Schalles",
    "City": "Gdańsk"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Maryellen",
    "Lastname": "Bord",
    "City": "Palembang"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Genovera",
    "Lastname": "Desai",
    "City": "Basra"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Fina",
    "Lastname": "Thad",
    "City": "Mecca"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Emylee",
    "Lastname": "Flita",
    "City": "Vancouver"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Aurore",
    "Lastname": "Lipson",
    "City": "Makati City"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Florie",
    "Lastname": "Hachmin",
    "City": "Douala"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Brooks",
    "Lastname": "Grayce",
    "City": "Birmingham"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Kristan",
    "Lastname": "Allina",
    "City": "Bahía Blanca"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Dorothy",
    "Lastname": "Remmer",
    "City": "Nouméa"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Kittie",
    "Lastname": "Kussell",
    "City": "Detroit"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Lexine",
    "Lastname": "Letsou",
    "City": "Palikir"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Madelle",
    "Lastname": "Joseph",
    "City": "Mwanza"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Olivette",
    "Lastname": "Faust",
    "City": "Pelotas"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Damaris",
    "Lastname": "Slifka",
    "City": "Graz"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Dennie",
    "Lastname": "Merat",
    "City": "Abuja"
},
{
    "Firstname": "Augustine",
    "Lastname": "Burnside",
    "City": "Arbil"
}
]
```

Comment: Are those views using the same model?

Comment: No, they have two different QStandardItemModel's. Both QTreeViews have a custom delegate HTMLDelegate() class that is made for rich-text formating.

Comment: I have read about [QAbstractScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractscrollarea.html) and [QWidgets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#mapFrom) mapFrom functions, but i cant figure out how to implement the required logic with those two.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you want to do and where the problem is. The code above seems to find a match in the right view, and both `scrollTo()` and selection model's `select()` should do what you want. Can you please clarify the problem and also provide a more comprehensive [mre] along with the procedure we should follow to reproduce the problem (and the expected result)?

Comment: @musicamante I added a MRE for clarification and hope that helps :)

Comment: For future reference, please ensure that you provide any MRE as a single code block, otherwise we need to do lots of editing in order to make the code run. We must be able to copy, paste and run with minimum efforts in order to reproduce your code, so that we can actually focus on the problem at hand without being distracted (and annoyed) in recreating it to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt doesn't provide a way to position an item at a specific position. But [`scrollTo()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo) actually has a second optional argument that allows to ensure that the item is shown at a "reference" position.

Knowing that, we can try to scroll to the index and show it at the *bottom*, then manually update the vertical scroll bar value until it reaches the required position.

**WARNING**: this can only work properly as long as:

- both views are fundamentally identical, including:

  - size (most importantly, their height);
  - same font, icon sizes, etc;
  - same scroll mode (possibly, using `ScrollPerItem`);
- **all** items of *both* views have the same height;

If any of the above is not respected, you'll get unexpected results. There might also be inconsistencies in case *one* of the view is showing the horizontal scroll bar and the other isn't, specifically when the left view is scrolled to the bottom and when the horizontal scroll bar is shown the viewport cannot show *full* items only.

I modified your function also adding the `index` parameter that the [`doubleClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked) signal automatically provides.

I also changed the search function to the more conventional [`QAbstractItemModel.match()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match), removing the `Qt.MatchRecursive` flag, since you only want to match top level items of both the source and destination models.

Finally, you generally only need to use `setCurrentIndex()`, and using the `Select` flag alone will *update* the selection, possibly showing multiple selected items (the proper flag would be `ClearAndSelect`). Also, you should *never* use persistent references to the selection model (the reason is explained in the [`setModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setModel)) documentation).

```py
    def double_clicked(self, index):
        if not index.isValid() or index.parent().isValid():
            return

        right_model = self.tree_view_right.model()
        matches = right_model.match(right_model.index(0, 0), 
            Qt.DisplayRole, index.data())
        if not matches:
            return

        right_index = matches[0]
        self.tree_view_right.setCurrentIndex(right_index)
        self.tree_view_right.scrollTo(right_index, 
            QAbstractItemView.PositionAtBottom)

        leftRect = self.tree_view_left.visualRect(index)
        sb = self.tree_view_right.verticalScrollBar()
        sbMax = sb.maximum()
        while sb.value() < sbMax:
            rightRect = self.tree_view_right.visualRect(right_index)
            if (
                leftRect.contains(rightRect) # the visual rects match
                or leftRect.y() > rightRect.y() # the right rect is above
            ):
                break
            sb.setValue(sb.value() + 1)
```

Note that the `leftRect.y() > rightRect.y()` condition is required in case the source item is next the first top rows of the model *and* any item above it is expanded, while the left match is not; consider this case:

1. at their current sizes, the views can only show 10 items;
2. expand the first two top level items on the left view;
3. the right view has all items collapsed;
4. double click the last visible item on the left, which is now the eighth top level item;
5. `scrollTo(index, PositionAtBottom)` can only *try* to show the index at the bottom of the view, but since the views can only show 10 items, the eighth item on the right will never be at the bottom;